# Unity - error CS1501: No overload for method `#####' takes `1' arguments

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I keep getting this error when I run my code and I can't quite see what the problem is:

error CS1501: No overload for method checkStatus' takes `1' arguments

In my enemyHealth script I have:

```
void Update() 
{
    checkStatus (0);
}

public void checkStatus()
{
    if (currentHealth > maxHealth)
        currentHealth = maxHealth;

    if (currentHealth <= 0)
        death();
}
```

and in my playerAttack script I have:

```
private void Attack()
{
    enemyHealth eh = (enemyHealth)target.GetComponent ();
    eh.checkStatus (-10);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error message should be plain - you're calling the `checkStatus` method with a single argument, while it is declared with no arguments.

Either you need to add an argument to the method declaration (and use it somehow), or you need to change the calls to pass no argument.

It seems that your intent is to either lower the health and check if the character survived - if that's the case, something like this might work:

```
public void Damage(int amount)
{
  currentHealth -= amount;

  if (currentHealth > maxHealth)
    currentHealth = maxHealth;

  if (currentHealth <= 0)
    death();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the problem, you're passing one argument to your checkstatus method. Resolve it, by adding a parameter or removing your argument.

```
checkStatus (0);
eh.checkStatus (-10);
```